# PHP Image Uploaded Name won't change

Tags: php

I have PHP function to upload file (image).

```
foreach($_FILES['wallpaperFile']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmpName)
{
    $file_name = $_FILES['wallpaperFile']['name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['wallpaperFile']['type'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['wallpaperFile']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp  = $_FILES['wallpaperFile']['tmp_name'][$key];

    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"assets/img/wallpapers/".time().$file_name);
}
```

It's working and I can see the data image uploaded on my folder.

But now how can I set the image file name only `time()` without `.$file_name`

If I remove `.$file_name`, file uploaded is not correct without extension and only 1 file, even though I uploaded 3 files.

Example:

> Image file name: 1510750186shubuh.jpg
>
> What I want only
>
> 1510750186.jpg

Comment: be careful with paths like `test/123456`. If the path separator get changed to \ there can be some unexpected behaviors because `\1` (or another number) can be interpreted as special character. To avoid something like this you can use a path like `test/img-12345`. (*I made some experience with this.*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) for this, with `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` flag, Like:

```
foreach($_FILES['wallpaperFile']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmpName)
{
    $file_name = $_FILES['wallpaperFile']['name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['wallpaperFile']['type'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['wallpaperFile']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp  = $_FILES['wallpaperFile']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"assets/img/wallpapers/".time().'.'.$ext);
}
```

This will only add the extension and no the full file name.

**Edit:**

To upload multiple files at the same time try to use 1 of these:

```
$newFileName = time()."{$key}.{$ext}";
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"assets/img/wallpapers/".$newFileName);
```

Or

```
$newFileName = str_replace('.','',microtime(true)).".{$ext}";
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"assets/img/wallpapers/".$newFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the extension of the file is your problem here. It's that `time()` only has a one-second resolution. It's highly improbable that `time()` will have a different value in any iteration of that loop. As such all your files have the same name with just `time()`.

It's probably better to use something like `microtime(true)`, which has microsecond fidelity or `uniqid()` to get a higher resolution in the same request.

```
foreach($_FILES['wallpaperFile']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmpName)
{
    $file_name = $_FILES['wallpaperFile']['name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['wallpaperFile']['type'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['wallpaperFile']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp  = $_FILES['wallpaperFile']['tmp_name'][$key];

    /* user either this */
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"assets/img/wallpapers/" . microtime(true));

    /* or this */
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"assets/img/wallpapers/" . uniqid());
}
```

You can see the difference by simply printing the value of both `time()` and `microtime(true)` inside that loop to realize the problem that `time()` would pose on your requirements here.

```
foreach($_FILES['wallpaperFile']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmpName)
{
    echo "time(): ", time(), "<br>\n";
    echo "microtime(true): ", microtime(true), "<br>\n";
    echo "uniqid(): ", uniqid(), "<br>\n";
}
```

> ## Warning
>
> You should **never rely** on `$_FILES['wallpaperFile']['name']` here, because it is user-supplied input, and as such it is vulnerable to manipulation. Avoid allowing the client to possibly exploit/manipulate your filesystem by handing them direct-access to it via this vector. Having a completely random filename on your filesystem, instead, and storing that random name in your database to associate it with some arbitrary user-supplied-input is preferrable, because it allows you to retain full-control over your server's file system while still allowing the user to retain control over their own data.