# PHP fileupload giving all filenames from array

Tags: php, file-upload

I've been looking in this for a day or two now. When I upload multiple files to this script, "$finalfilename" gives me back multiple filenames from the second file.

Here's my code:

```
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/config/config.php");

$valid_extensions = array(
    'jpeg',
    'jpg',
    'png',
    'gif',
    'bmp'
); // valid extensions
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/uploads/'; // upload directory
$uploadOK = 1;
$album = strip_tags($_POST['newPostForm-Album']);
$i = 0;

foreach($_FILES['NEW-POST-FORM_IMAGES']['name'] as $file)
{
    $imgname = $_FILES['NEW-POST-FORM_IMAGES']['name'][$i];
    $tmpname = $_FILES['NEW-POST-FORM_IMAGES']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $timestamp = time();
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($imgname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $newfilename = sha1(time() . $i);
    $finalfilename = $newfilename . "." . $extension;
    if ($_FILES['NEW-POST-FORM_IMAGES']["size"][$i] > 500000)
    {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if ($uploadOK)
    {
        if (in_array($extension, $valid_extensions))
        {
            $path = $path . strtolower($finalfilename);
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $path))
            {

                // mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO posts VALUES('', '$album', '$finalfilename', '$timestamp')");

                echo $_FILES['NEW-POST-FORM_IMAGES']['name'][$i];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "error!";
            }
        }
    }

    $imgname = "";
    $tmpname = "";
    $timestamp = "";
    $extension = "";
    $newfilename = "";
    $finalfilename = "";
    $i++;
}
```

As you can see, I tried resetting all the strings at the end before adding $i.

UPDATE

I tried using $file instead of $_FILES (echo $file['name'][$i];)
This gives me back this warning:
Illegal string offset 'name' in

also the output of the second file ($finalfilename) gives me 'filename'.extention'filename'.extention
ea5816965b01dae0b19072606596c01efc015334.jpeg21aa3008f90c89059d981bdc51b458ca1954ab46.jpg

Which need to be separated.

I need to only get the filename of each file separately.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `$_FILES['NEW-POST-FORM_IMAGES']['name'][$i]` in your loop you should just use `$file` I think.

Comment: @xander: it should be the same.

Comment: @xander as panther said, it is the same, I tried both, thanks for the help anyway ;)

Comment: Still recommend using $file else you could also go for a while loop.

Comment: What exactly means `give's me back multiple filenames from the second file.`? Please add a dump from `$_FILES['NEW-POST-FORM_IMAGES']['name']` too.

Comment: As I use the $file['name'][$i], it gives me this warning '<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'name' in <b>/Users/axeldolislager/Documents/GitHub/noreplypictures/website/includes/form_handlers/new-post_handler.php</b> on line <b>31</b><br />
1<br />'

Comment: I'll edit the post

Comment: Go for: `foreach($_FILES['NEW-POST-FORM_IMAGES'] as $file)` than it works.

Comment: Try the solution on this question instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47307886/2394254

Comment: You also never reset the path so it will end in: path/filename/filename/filename ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in `$path` variable.

Put `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/uploads/';` into the loop. You can remove variable reseting from the end too.

```
foreach ($_FILES['NEW-POST-FORM_IMAGES']['name'] as $file) {
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/uploads/';
    $imgname = $_FILES['NEW-POST-FORM_IMAGES']['name'][$i];
    $tmpname = $_FILES['NEW-POST-FORM_IMAGES']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $timestamp = time();
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($imgname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $newfilename = sha1(time() . $i);
    $finalfilename = $newfilename . "." . $extension;
    if ($_FILES['NEW-POST-FORM_IMAGES']["size"][$i] > 500000)
    {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if ($uploadOK)
    {
        if (in_array($extension, $valid_extensions))
        {
            $path = $path . strtolower($finalfilename);
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $path))
            {

                // mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO posts VALUES('', '$album', '$finalfilename', '$timestamp')");

                echo $_FILES['NEW-POST-FORM_IMAGES']['name'][$i];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "error!";
            }
        }
    }

    $i++;
}
```

There are more thing to update, instead of foreach for/while would be better here, or using foreach in else way (use `$file` in the loop body), etc. Moving `$path` into loop is easiest way how to fix your problem.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your help!